# Skype for Business UCWA and Web API with Office365

Tags: asp.net-web-api, office365api, skype-for-business, ucwa, skypedeveloper

Is it possible to connect to Office365 server and use UCWA (ucwa.skype.com/) with Skype for Business now?

I want to use this example https://www.matthewproctor.com/Send-An-IM-With-UCWA-Creating-the-Application/ but I don't know which server I can use to connect...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like this capability was announced at [BUILD 2016](http://www.ucguys.com/2016/03/skype-for-business-announcements-from-build-2016-conference.html). There is documentation on how get it running [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/mt590890(v=office.16).aspx).

Comment: Documentation was last modified: December 15, 2015; Is it the same, but now works with Office365 since BUILD 2016?

Answer (score 1):

No, as also stated in the UCWA wiki page here, or on official web site http://ucwa.skype.com

UCWA isn't available yet for Office 365, but only for on-premises Lync / S4B installation